# Google pie chart "No Data" how do I get data from php outputting json

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I am trying to generate a pie chart from a JSON created by a PHP webpage but I get a "No data" error. I have very little experience with JavaScript, I am probably not loading the data into the chart properly.

I have tried creating a JSON file and loading that instead the PHP but that did not change anything. I would like to keep the JSON output as close to the Google Visual pie chart example as possible to keep this example as simple as possible.

All files (except database connection) are in the same folder.

getData.php

```php
<?php
require_once("../../lib/db_connectPDOfinance.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM players_test";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$ar = [];
array_push($ar, array('Player', 'Score'));

if (isset($result)) foreach($result as $row)
{
    $player = $row['player'];
    $player = $player;
    $score = (int)$row['score'];

    array_push($ar, array($player, $score));
}

$out = array_values($ar);
echo json_encode($out);
?>
```

output from getData.php

```
[["Player","Score"],["Ace",27],["Bob",21],["Chris",25],["Dave",21],["James",25],["Joe",34]]
```

graph.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Player');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Score');

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
        });

        var options = {
          title: 'Experience Distribution'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected output is a pie chart actual output is chart title (Experience Distribution) and the text "No data" where the chart would be.

Answer (score 0):

Solved (reference: [Creating Pie Chart with Google Charts API from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755108/creating-pie-chart-with-google-charts-api-from-json))

I was not loading the data in graph.html I only told it where the data is.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Player');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Score');

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
        }).done(function (results) {
        Object.keys(results).forEach(function (index) {
            data.addRow([
              results[index][0],
              parseInt(results[index][1])
            ]);
        });
      });

        var options = {
          title: 'Experience Distribution'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```